# jquery-i18next - usage, change language by user, load translation from files

Tags: jquery, i18next

I was looking for an internationalization framework and came across [jqueryi-18next.js](https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next). I'm actually totally confused by using this plugin as the code in the sample file is different from the documentation.

My modified sample.html where I added two more language resources (de, fr), it is working fine when I change the "lng" value in the script.

```js
i18next.init({
        lng: 'de',
        resources: {
          en: {
            translation: {
              nav: {
                page1: 'Page One',
                page2: 'Page Two',
                page3: 'Page Three'
              }
            }
          },
          de: {
            translation: {
              nav: {
                page1: 'Seite Eins',
                page2: 'Seite Zwei',
                page3: 'Seite Drei'
              }
            }
          },
          fr: {
            translation: {
              nav: {
                page1: 'Page Un',
                page2: 'Page Deux',
                page3: 'Page Trois'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, function(err, t) {
        i18nextJquery.init(i18next, $);
        $('.nav').localize();
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-i18next/0.0.14/i18next-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/i18next/2.0.22/i18next.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page1"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page2"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

According to the docs the plugin is initialized using:

```
jqueryI18next.init(i18nextInstance, $, {...
```

Furthermore, if I load the jquery-i18next.min.js from the [repository](https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next) it doesn't work at all, I can only see the list item dots.

**What I basically would like to achieve is following:**

1. Changing the language using anchor links (en/de/fr) without reloading the whole page.
2. Load the translations from files. I did save three translation.json files according to the docs in locales with sub folders (en/de/fr) but without any success, only list item dots are visible! :(

I don't know how to do this and therefore I would really appreciate any help!

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I can answer both parts of your question.

1. You can add some anchor links and make them control the language quite easily. To change the language you just need to call `i18next.chngeLanguage` to set the new language and then call `$(elem).localize()` for every element you localize initially. In this example the language is updated if any of the `.lang-select` links are clicked.

```js
i18next.init({
        lng: 'de',
        resources: {
          en: {
            translation: {
              nav: {
                page1: 'Page One',
                page2: 'Page Two',
                page3: 'Page Three'
              }
            }
          },
          de: {
            translation: {
              nav: {
                page1: 'Seite Eins',
                page2: 'Seite Zwei',
                page3: 'Seite Drei'
              }
            }
          },
          fr: {
            translation: {
              nav: {
                page1: 'Page Un',
                page2: 'Page Deux',
                page3: 'Page Trois'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, function(err, t) {
        i18nextJquery.init(i18next, $);
        $('.nav').localize();

        $('.lang-select').click(function() {
          i18next.changeLanguage(this.innerHTML);
          $('.nav').localize();
        });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-i18next/0.0.14/i18next-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/i18next/2.0.22/i18next.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="lang-select">en</a>
<a href="#" class="lang-select">de</a>
<a href="#" class="lang-select">fr</a>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page1"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page2"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

2. To load from files on the server you need to use the [i18next-xhr-backend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend) for i18next. This examle won't be able to load the translations here but if you setup the directory structure shown below on the server then it should be able to load the translations as needed. You can also provide other values for `loadPath` to control how you want to store the files. To store all namespaces for each language in a single file use `loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}.json'` or to store all languages in a single file use `loadPath: '/locales.json'`.

```js
i18next
  .use(i18nextXHRBackend)
  .init({
      lng: 'de',
      backend: {
          loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
      }
    }, function(err, t) {
      jqueryI18next.init(i18next, $);
      $('.nav').localize();

      $('.lang-select').click(function() {
        i18next.changeLanguage(this.innerHTML, function() {
           $('.nav').localize();
        });
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-i18next/0.0.14/i18next-jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/i18next/2.0.22/i18next.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="lang-select">en</a>
<a href="#" class="lang-select">de</a>
<a href="#" class="lang-select">fr</a>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page1"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page2"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

The directory structre required:

```
locales
├── de
│   └── translation.json
├── dev
│   └── translation.json
├── en
│   └── translation.json
└── fr
    └── translation.json
```

Example translation.json:

```
{
    "nav": {
        "page1": "Seite Eins",
        "page2": "Seite Zwei",
        "page3": "Seite Drei"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed instruction, it works like a charm! i18nextXHRBackend only works when I put the whole file structure in the root directory of my webspace, uploading the files in a subfolder results in an error message from safari console saying "Failed to load resource ... status 404" and showing the url "www.mydomain/locales/de/translation.json" instead of "www.mydomain/subfolder/locales/de/translation.json". Do you have any idea for this behavior? Would you please tell me further what the purpose of "dev/translation.json" is? Many thanks!!

Comment: Yeah I think your choices are either to remove the first / from 'loadPath' which will make the path relative to the page where you load them. This will only work if you only have a single level of pages (so that the relative path is always the same). Alternatively you could make loadPath the full path including the subfolder: '/subfolder/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'. In certain situations this may not be possible though so YMMV.

Comment: 'dev' is the default 'fallback language' meaning that if you have a key which is not present in the current language then it will be looked up there as well. You can control the name of this with the 'fallbackLng' option. If you want I can make an example but I'll have to edit into the answer as there's not space in the comments.

Comment: loadPath is working now, it wasn't wrapped in "backend {}", my fault! ;)! fallbackLng is working as well! Many thanks again, you made my day!!!

Comment: I think that's my bad because I didn't include that in my example as I'm used to version 1 where it wasn't required. I've edited the answer. Could you please just confirm it's correct now?

Comment: No big deal! Yes, it is correct now! Thanks a lot again!!

Comment: One thing I'd like to point out here is that in example NO. 2 - To load from files on the server..., you need to put the second  $('nav').localize() inside a function then put in in i18next.changeLanguage(this.innerHTML,callback), otherwise, you won't see language got changed as in No. 1. This is because it involves in ajax call, i18next doest not have the needed locale when it is asked to localize immediately, thankfully, i18next has callbacks. 
e.g.
$('.lang-select').click(function() {
        i18next.changeLanguage(this.innerHTML);
        $('.nav').localize();
      });

Comment: @vichsu thanks for the info! I made an edit to the answer to reflect this. Could you please confirm that it is correct now?

Comment: fyi: there is a newer jquery-i18next guide here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3